# Pandas/Python formatting issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am having an issue formatting a .txt file output from a pandas script. the desired outcome will have a single space separating the columns of data but my output txt file has 2 spaces separating each column for the first three columns. I have tried a few different space stripping options but have come up empty handed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO2mX.png)

Comment: please provide more detail and a minimum working example code of your problem. Do you have leading/ trailing spaces in these columns? what dtype are they?

Comment: let me try to post a picture of the output file...

Comment: when you click the image link it will pull up a txt file that shows the first two lines formatted the way i need and the remining lines formatted the way that is currently being output

Comment: can you post the first few (10) lines of data? There should be a way to set the delimitator.

Comment: there is a link above to an image of the data

Comment: The image is not useful as it does not show any white space characters.